# plone.app.theming with lxml error on Windows

Tags: plone

I want to install Plone addon named **plone.app.theming**. It using installation with buildout

Sorry. imgur service was reject pictures and I was push some image links here.

A longed install process was ended the error with LXML library. [cmd log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2052kKMN8_WSWFOY2QwUmU4bzg)

> "." not command or packet file. CMMI failed

Traceback lead to zc.buildout. It isn't issue.

I am opened app.themes buildout.cfg and erase LXML from list.

Next step:

> python -m pip install lxml==3.6.0

Success. Unfortunately lxml was stand alone now w/o links to lxml.elementtree and libxml2.

[cmd log2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2052kKMN8_WTmpJNHV4cjB0TlE/view?usp=sharing)

> Couldn't find a distribution for 'elementtree==1.2.7 ...'

I am trying to last binary way. **Wheel** was installed.

Result: multiple failures with pip, wheel and other.

After buildout's work is ended I find lxml 2.3 ver in /eggs of my folder to app-theming !

**What way to change lxml version at buildout of plone.app.theming** ? How to erase linked old lxml package at downloading? Also elementree==1.2.8 may be have a changed with update lxml to newest.

Comment: We need to see your buildout.cfg and the text of the error messages (not screen shots). You may have more luck asking your question in https://community.plone.org.

Comment: For elementtree, search the webz for the exact name given in the err-msg, download and include it as a development-egg. If you still get lxml-errs I'd recommend to use a Unified-Installler (Thanks to Steve McMahon & Co., providing and maintaining these).

Comment: Do you have a versions.cfg file? If so, this file contains a list of the installed eggs and their version numbers on your Plone site. This is the version number the buildout looks for when you run the command. In your situation, you just need to change the 'elementtree==1.2.7' to 'elementtree==1.2.8' in your versions.cfg file since this is the version you have downloaded in the eggs directory.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu to trying to resolve this issue. After I successfully installed the elementtree1.2.7 as an egg and unpack it uses python command. So restarted buildout and console are success going abroad to next operation.